# How to write two colums table as an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple table with 2 colums: `ID` and `Name`. It looks like this:

```
License_ID      License_Name
   5             xxx
   8             yyy
   13            zzz
```

I want to write this table as an array, and I want to be able to find the `license_id` when `license_name` is provided. How can I write this array?

Edit: I can write the array the same as the answer nickb provided,

```
$array = array(
    'xxx' => 5,
    'yyy' => 8,
    'zzz' => 13
);
```

but I want to have the license_id and license_name as key instead of using value of license_name as key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form an array with keys corresponding to the license name and values corresponding to the license ID, like so:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table'; // Optionally add a WHERE clause
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
$array = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result))
{
    // Form the array
    $array[ $row['License_Name'] ] = $row['License_ID'];
}
mysql_free_result( $result);
```

To omit the table and use a global variable, use the same technique:

```
$array = array(
    'xxx' => 5,
    'yyy' => 8,
    'zzz' => 13
);
```

Now, to lookup the license ID, all you need is:

```
$license_id = 8;
$id = $array[ $license_id ]; // $id = 'yyy';
```

**Edit:** Here's an alternative way to represent the way in a more clear manner:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'license_id' => 5,
        'license_name' => 'xxx'
    ),
    array(
        'license_id' => 8,
        'license_name' => 'yyy'
    ),
    array(
        'license_id' => 13,
        'license_name' => 'zzz'
    )
);
```

Then, to find the license_id when license_name is provided, loop to find your result:

```
$license_name = 'zzz';
foreach( $array as $entry)
{
    if( $entry['license_name'] == $license_name)
    {
        echo 'Found ID of ' . $license_name . ' - ' . $entry['license_id'];
        break;
    }
}
```

OR, and even more direct way to prevent looping is to modify the above technique to have each sub-array contain the license_name as its key, like so:

```
$array = array(
    'xxx' => array(
        'license_id' => 5,
        'license_name' => 'xxx'
    ),
    'yyy' => array(
        'license_id' => 8,
        'license_name' => 'yyy'
    ),
    'zzz' => array(
        'license_id' => 13,
        'license_name' => 'zzz'
    )
);
```

Now, to find the license_id, you can do it directly once you know the license_name:

```
$license_name = 'zzz';
$license_id = $array[ $license_name ]['license_id'];
```

Comment: thanks! but I don't want to create a sql table for this. I prefer to write an array and store it as a globle var in my program.

Comment: @Jenny - Your OP mentioned table, so I figured this is what you wanted. You can still use the same technique - I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @Jenny your technique may face issues when the amount of data is large. In that case it will be better to write to disk in the form of a dB table rather than keeping it in memory

Comment: @nickb, thanks! can I have the keys in this array? I mean, not just 'xxx'=>5, but say it clearly 'license_id'=>5, 'license_name'=>'xxx'

Comment: @Jenny yes, `$array['license_id'] = 5;`

Comment: @s992 , on a blank paper, how do you write down this array? just say $array['license_id'] = 5, then, where's the license name, and how the pair match?

Comment: @Jenny - I've updated my answer to provide as many options as possible that I can think of.

Comment: @nickb , thanks so much for the detailed instructions! Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Jenny Glad I could help `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You know there is array_search out there,don't you? Personally I like to keep array keys as ids or numeric value.. so in your example `$key=array_search('xxx',$myArr);` (where id is the key and name is the value) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php